# And en elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

he empezado hace poco a experimentar con elasticsearch y no consigo hacer un AND.

Tengo dos objetos como los siguientes:

```
"objeto1": [{"id": 1,"tipo": [{"id": 1,"valor": 5},{"id": 2,"valor": 4},{"id": 3,"valor": 2}]}]

"objeto2": [{"id": 2,"tipo": [{"id": 1,"valor": 2},{"id": 2,"valor": 1},{"id": 3,"valor": 6}]}]
```

Quiero filtrar los objetos que dentro del array "tipo" tengan un objeto con "id" 3 y "valor" 2.
He intentado utilizar la expresión MUST de elasticsearch para hacer el AND.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {
                    "term": {"tipo.id":3}
                },
                {
                    "term": {"tipo.valor":2}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Pero este me devuelve ambos objetos, ya que dentro de objeto1 y objeto 2 hay campos con "id" 3 y "valor" 2.
Mi intención seria que me devolviera solo el objeto1, ya que es el único que tiene dentro de "tipo" un objeto con "id" 3 y "valor" 2.

```
{
 "id": 3,
 "valor": 2
}
```

¿Como se podría hacer un AND para que me filtre por dos campos?

Comment: Documentación oficial: https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query Aunque me da que estás intentando algo más complejo que un AND, pues entras en un subnivel de la jerarquía de datos.

Comment: Para hacer un búsqueda en valores anidadados debe estar indexado con el tipo nested en el mapping. Mas información: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo sería comprobar como tienes configurados los mappings de tus índices. Deberías de tenerlo así:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "tipo": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "valor": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Por otro lado, la query quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
{
"query": {
"nested": {
  "path": "tipo",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": {"tipo.valor": 2}},
        { "match": {"tipo.id": 3}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se que version de elastic tenes, pero seguramente te conviene usar filter, donde le pasas una lista de filtros, quedria algo asi:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tipo.id": "3"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "tipo.valor": "2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva!